# Opponents keep reference to old ball instead of newly-spawned ball

Tags: unity, c#

I have the position of a ball that the opponents get and reach for it.

When the ball is destroyed, according to my idea, a new one should be created and opponents should reach for it instead.

The ball is created, but the opponents refer to the old ball. How can I make the opponents reach for the new balls too?

```cs
public class EnemyPoint : MonoBehaviour {
     public float speed = 5;
     Transform ball;
     public float stoppingDistance;
     public float force = 5000f;
     public GameObject keepHolding;
     public GameObject myEnemy;
 
    
     private float spawnRangeX = 10;
     private float spawnZMin = 15; 
     private float spawnZMax = 25;
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ball").transform;
 
         Instantiate(ball.transform, GenerateSpawnPosition(), ball.transform.rotation);
         
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         EnemyWalk();
     }
 
     private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
     {
         Vector3 dir = ball.position - transform.position;
        
         if (ball)
         {
             
             other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = dir.normalized * force * Time.deltaTime ;
     
         }
        
     }
 
     void EnemyWalk()
     {
         float rangeX = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -50, 65);
         float rangeY = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, 5, 5);
         float rangeZ = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, -55, -55);
 
         myEnemy.transform.position = new Vector3(rangeX, rangeY, rangeZ);
 
         if (Vector3.Distance(keepHolding.transform.position, ball.position) < stoppingDistance)
         {
             myEnemy.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(myEnemy.transform.position, ball.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
 
     }
     Vector3 GenerateSpawnPosition()
     {   
         float xPos = Random.Range(-spawnRangeX, spawnRangeX);
         float zPos = Random.Range(spawnZMin, spawnZMax);
         return new Vector3(xPos, 3, zPos);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your instantiate is creating a new object but you don't store it anywhere, means ball is still the old one. Don't see any code that handles destroy or creating new balls though

Comment: it is destroyed in another script. I thought "Instantiate" creates a clone of mine "ball", 
what should i do to store it?

Comment: Yes it creates a clone of ball. But where are you looking for the clones position? Your enemyWalk goes to ball which is the original

Comment: Thanks to you I understood and tried all day how to use it. announced "public gameobject", but I can't get out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your comments right, all you need to do is assign the instantiated ball and just use it everywhere instead of the current ball.

```
private Transform spawnedBall;

void Start() {
   ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ball").transform;
   spawnedBall = Instantiate(ball.transform, GenerateSpawnPosition(), ball.transform.rotation);
}
```

So instead of

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
   Vector3 dir = ball.position - transform.position;
   ...
}
```

you change it to (and all other times you wrote `ball`)

```
Vector3 dir = spawnedBall.position - transform.position;
```

I'm not sure how it interacts with your other scripts or what happens to your original ball, how you destroy them or actually spawn new ones. But if you want to chase after the spawned ball, this should do the trick.

Comment: thanks you helped me a lot. I got it now. For some reason, I myself can’t think of it, write the creation of balls into a separate variable (